# VB.Net crystal report connection string

Tags: vb.net, string, crystal-reports, connection, report

I am using `vb.net 2010` to develop my software. Also have `crystal reports` in my projects and things are working perfectly in my PC.

My problem is that I design the crystal report in my PC with wizard and `my PC is not the server`, then upload it to the server so it would be accessible to users. But when try to open report a `connection problem` to the database pops up. I know that is due to the connection property when I designed the reports in my PC.

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Are you using DSN to connect to the database? Can you post your code for the connection?

Comment: What is DSN? All I do is use visual studio 2010 to design these reports.

Comment: do you mean DNS? Domain Name Server

Comment: Data Source Name = DSN. Somehow you need to connect your report to the data source (database). Obviously you can do it on your PC. But once you switch to your server, that data source is no longer accessible/available. So how are you connecting your report to the data source?

Comment: Exactly, that is my problem. I am asking about away to save the connection string to the database programatically so whatever is the server DSN I can just modify the source and then the reports works in any server.

Comment: You need to create the same DSN on your server that you have on your PC.

Comment: Got it. That is one way to solved the problem. But if I want to specify the server name in my code how that can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is showing the popup for giving userid and password. I want to give the server connection programatically.

[image]

i given the following code still it showing the popup

```
Private Sub CrystalReportViewer1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CrystalReportViewer1.Load
        Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
        Dim crtableLogoninfos As New TableLogOnInfos
        Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo
        Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo
        Dim CrTables As Tables
        Dim CrTable As Table
        cryRpt.Load("E:\ColorLab1\colorlab\colorlab\rpt_bill.rpt")

        With crConnectionInfo
            .ServerName = "MAHESH\SQLEXPRESS"
            .DatabaseName = "cc"
            .UserID = "erp"
            .Password = "123"
        End With

        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables
        For Each CrTable In CrTables
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
        Next
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    End Sub
```

**How can i solve this?**

Comment: This is the way I could solve my problem. Other solutions are almost the same but they involve changing my pc name which I did not like. In this solution you put the server name in the code and that's it.

Answer (score 4):

Add this code in the module(for common access)

```
 Public Sub SetReportDb(ByVal ConnectionString As String, ByRef CrystalReportViewer As CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer, ByRef reportDocument As ReportClass)
        'Get SQL Server Details
        Dim builder As New System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder()

        builder.ConnectionString = ConnectionString


        Dim zServer As String = TryCast(builder("Data Source"), String)
        Dim zDatabase As String = TryCast(builder("Initial Catalog"), String)
        Dim zUsername As String = TryCast(builder("User ID"), String)
        Dim zPassword As String = TryCast(builder("Password"), String)

        Dim ciReportConnection As New ConnectionInfo

        ciReportConnection.ServerName = zServer
        ciReportConnection.DatabaseName = zDatabase
        ciReportConnection.UserID = zUsername
        ciReportConnection.Password = zPassword

        'Assign data source details to tables

        For Each table As Table In reportDocument.Database.Tables
            table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ciReportConnection
            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(table.LogOnInfo)
        Next

        For Each subrep As ReportDocument In reportDocument.Subreports
            For Each table As Table In subrep.Database.Tables
                table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ciReportConnection
                table.ApplyLogOnInfo(table.LogOnInfo)
            Next
        Next

        'Assign data source details to the report viewer
        If CrystalReportViewer.LogOnInfo IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim tlInfo As TableLogOnInfos = CrystalReportViewer.LogOnInfo
            For Each tbloginfo As TableLogOnInfo In tlInfo
                tbloginfo.ConnectionInfo = ciReportConnection
            Next
        End If
        reportDocument.VerifyDatabase()
        reportDocument.Refresh()
        CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = reportDocument
        CrystalReportViewer.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

Inside each crystal report viewer give the below code it will  override the old connection with connectionstring

```
 Private Sub CrystalReportViewer1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CrystalReportViewer1.Load
        SetReportDb(My.Settings.colorlabConnectionString, CrystalReportViewer1, rpt_inwardreport1)
    End Sub
```

Comment: This is very good answer. It reduces writing same code for every report.

Answer (score 2):

So to put this into a proper answer:

Your first problem is solved by creating the same DSN on your server that you have on your PC.
Your second problem can be solved using code that looks something like this:

```
connection.DatabaseName = [DatabaseName]
connection.UserID = [UserID]
connection.ServerName = [ServerName]
connection.Password = [Password]
```

or

```
myCrystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("myUsername", "myPassword","servername","dbname");
```

Comment: I did this. I have added the login details and changed the server name in my code to the server, but still I am having a problem: Failed to open the connection. Details: [database vendor code: 17]....!

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is a few years old, but after struggling with these same problems, I thought I would add a variation of Mahesh ML's routine for MS SQL 2016 server.

A three things to note:

- `SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder` is used instead of DbConnectionStringBuilder
- `zSecurity` (added) for Window's authentication instead of database user
- `reportDocument.DataSourceConnections(0).IntegratedSecurity = True` is needed when Windows authentication is used

  ```
  Public Sub SetReportSQL(ByVal ConnectionString As String,
                     ByRef CrystalReportViewer As CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer,
                     ByRef reportDocument As ReportClass)
      'Get SQL Server Details
      Dim builder As New SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder

      builder.ConnectionString = ConnectionString

      Dim zServer As String = TryCast(builder("Data Source"), String)
      Dim zDatabase As String = TryCast(builder("Initial Catalog"), String)
      Dim zSecurity As Boolean = Boolean.TryParse(builder("Integrated Security"), zSecurity)
      Dim zUsername As String = TryCast(builder("User ID"), String)
      Dim zPassword As String = TryCast(builder("Password"), String)

      Dim ciReportConnection As New ConnectionInfo

      ciReportConnection.ServerName = zServer
      ciReportConnection.DatabaseName = zDatabase
      ciReportConnection.IntegratedSecurity = zSecurity
      If zSecurity = False Then
          ciReportConnection.UserID = zUsername
          ciReportConnection.Password = zPassword
      Else
          reportDocument.DataSourceConnections(0).IntegratedSecurity = True
      End If

      'Assign data source details to tables
      For Each table As Table In reportDocument.Database.Tables
          table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ciReportConnection
          table.ApplyLogOnInfo(table.LogOnInfo)
      Next

      For Each subrep As ReportDocument In reportDocument.Subreports
          For Each table As Table In subrep.Database.Tables
              table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ciReportConnection
              table.ApplyLogOnInfo(table.LogOnInfo)
          Next
      Next

      'Assign data source details to the report viewer
      If CrystalReportViewer.LogOnInfo IsNot Nothing Then
          Dim tlInfo As TableLogOnInfos = CrystalReportViewer.LogOnInfo
          For Each tbloginfo As TableLogOnInfo In tlInfo
              tbloginfo.ConnectionInfo = ciReportConnection
          Next
      End If
      reportDocument.VerifyDatabase()
      reportDocument.Refresh()
      CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = reportDocument
      CrystalReportViewer.Refresh()
  End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys i got the answer

```
 Private Sub rpt_billform_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo.Item(0).ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "MAHESH\SQLEXPRESS"
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo.Item(0).ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "cc"
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo.Item(0).ConnectionInfo.UserID = "erp"
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo.Item(0).ConnectionInfo.Password = "123"
End Sub
```

Comment: This is fine but in my pc is the development environment of all my prior projects and sometime needs to modify one project. This will make changing the pc name many times inefficient. So need to have programmable solution.